# Xcode 7.0 beta / IOS9 / WatchOS 2 - no symbols for paired Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch, ios9, watchos-2

I got this message within Xcode, any idea how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3380:

> Xcode failed to download the symbol files from
>   http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/watchOS_13S5255d/Watch1_1_13S5255d.dmg.
>   I was successful to launch my watchOS app by following steps.
>
> 1. Download the symbol file installer for 13S5255c from http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/watchOS_13S5255c/Watch1_1_13S5255c.dmg.
> 2. Create directory "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/watchOS DeviceSupport/2.0 (13S5255d)/Symbols"
> 3. Mount the DMG and open Watch1,1.pkg.
> 4. Change the destination directory to above directory. (DO NOT install to default location! OS X will be destroyed!)
> 5. Install symbol files.
> 6. Open project on Xcode 7 beta.
> 7. Disconnect and connect iPhone.

Comment: Please do not plagiarise. You've at least linked to your source in this post, but you *haven't* made clear that the entirety of your post prior to the link is a verbatim copy-and-paste of somebody else's work. I'm wrapping it in a quote block to make this more apparent; please make clear when you are copying and pasting other people's work in future.

Comment: Solution no longer working with Xcode V7.0 beta 4 (7A165t). And the download link is no longer available, too.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me is based on the earlier post, but to simplify things I’ve followed the initial steps, changed the directory name to work with Beta 5 and zipped the relevant folders. So the simplified version for Beta 5 is:

1. Download the zip file from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pioqipz2mlhy0ye/watchOS%20DeviceSupport.zip?dl=0) to the target directory: ~/Users/[user]/Library/Developer/Xcode
2. Unzip the file.  You should see a new folder named “WatchOS DeviceSupport” under your Xcode folder, with another folder named “2.0 (13S5325c)”.

[image]

3. Open project on Xcode 7 beta.
4. Disconnect and connect your iPhone.

That’s all – it worked for me, I hope it will work for you as well.

I couldn't post the image, you can find the complete post [here](http://technofob.com/bug-no-symbols-for-paired-apple-watch-ios-9-watchos-2-xcode-7-all-under-beta-5/).

Comment: directory is wrong, should be ~/Library/Developer/Xcode

Comment: Well, now my iPhone says "no paired Apple Watch". I've had tons of issues keeping the watch connected.

Answer (score 1):

in case anyone is still struggling with this, i was able to solve by updating to the most recent version of xcode.

everything was working until watchos 2 beta 5 installed on my watch, then i got this error.  updating to xcode 7 beta 5 allowed my watch to appropriately have the new symbols installed.